# Getting rid of tracked and untracked changes and going back to a previous state

Tags: git

If after doing `git status` I have

1. some unstaged but tracked changes (modified files)
2. some unstaged but untracked files (including new files)

What is the correct way to get rid of these. In clearer words, I want my files to be exactly as they  were before they were changed or delete the new ones.

(Take into account that I might have also staged files that I want to commit)

Comment: Why not `git stash` it? you sure you want to delete it entirely?

Comment: I have been using stash so far. It works well, but I am wondering about how to do it if I want to delete it entirely

Comment: I think there are a number of ways to go about this. `git reset <commit> --hard` will remove the changes for the tracked files. I don't think it touches the untracked files. I think one way to get both is to `git stash save` and then `git stash drop` it if you're really looking to delete it. I can suggest a more complete answer later.

Comment: @astrochun To do this (destroy untracked files, including ignored ones) with `git stash`, you would need `git stash -a && git stash drop`, but this has pretty much the same effect as `git clean -fx && git reset --hard`, which is usually better because it is faster and more understandable.

Answer (score 2):

To delete *untracked* files, use `git clean`.  Be aware that this operation *cannot be undone by Git* (your OS may, or may not, provide some means of restoring deleted files, but an *untracked* file is, by definition, not in Git's index, which typically means it's not in Git at all, so Git can't get it back).

To remove files with `git clean`, you must use the `-f` option.  This will remove *some* untracked files, but not the untracked-and-ignored ones.  To remove those files as well, use the `-x` option as well.  To remove emptied directories, add the `-d` option too:

```
git clean -dfx
```

Having deleted those files that *aren't* in Git at all, you can then use `git reset --hard commit` to move the current branch name *to* the specified commit and check out that commit, or `git reset --hard` to leave the current branch name where it is, but re-set all index and working tree copies of files to match the current commit.  Or, you can use `git checkout -f --detach commit` to forcibly check out the given commit, overriding the usual check to make sure that this is not discarding modified files.  The `--detach` status results in a detached HEAD, even if you use a branch name to select the commit.

It's rarely a good idea to do this, but special occasions do occur.

Comment: `git clean -dfxn` will show you what files will be deleted without deleting them `-n` is the "dry run" option